# TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got array

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to convert an array containing images into a tensor, but I'm getting error "TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got array"

images.shape = (10,)

images[0].shape = (375,500,3) and 
images[1].shape = (400,500,3).. i.e. the images[i] have various shapes.

imgs = tf.convert_to_tensor(images)

I'm not sure how to solve this, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
imgs = tf.convert_to_tensor(images[0])
```

If all of your images are of the same shape. Otherwise you have to resize them to a same dimension then call the code.